# The second query in a nested if else loop doesn't return an exceptions message

Tags: php, sql, loops, exception, if-statement

The code below currently successfully checks a table of values that matches that of the user input      = $upn and returns "No pupil exists." If no values are found.  I now wish to run another check of a different table. The second query is a very similar check to the previous query, apart from checking for a project rather than a pupil.

These two queries are currently organized as you see here. Project query under Pupil query. The     project query doesn't return No Project exists. When the user enters an invalid value.

I think it may be something to do with putting the second query after the while loop of the first query.

Is there a way of getting these two queries to work?

Thank you for your time.

```
{
$query = mysql_query("SELECT pupil_forename, pupil_surname FROM pupil WHERE pupil_id = '$upn'");
    $count = mysql_num_rows($query);
    if ($count == 0 ) {
        $output = "No Pupil exists.";     
    } else{        
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
            $fname = $row['pupil_forename'];
            $sname = $row['pupil_surname'];

    $proquery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM project WHERE project_code = '$project'");
        $count = mysql_num_rows($proquery);
        if ($count == 0 ) {
            $output = "No Project exists.";
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that there is no value returned and $output does not contain "No Prjects exists."? You never output $output;

Comment: stick an `else` on the second if statement and loop through to see if anything is actually returned.

Comment: I think you may need to edit your code again, it is all sorts of wrong now..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT pupil_forename, pupil_surname FROM pupil WHERE pupil_id = '$upn'");
$count = mysql_num_rows($query);
if ($count == 0 ) {
    $output = "No Pupil exists.";     
} else {        
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
        $fname = $row['pupil_forename'];
        $sname = $row['pupil_surname'];
    }
}

$proquery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM project WHERE project_code = '$project'");
$count = mysql_num_rows($proquery);
if ($count == 0 ) {
    $output = "No Project exists.";
}
```